# How can I set different animation-delay for all animation's child elements?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to give different animation delays to all of my animation container's child elements to make them appear slowly. Here is my project's codepen link: https://codepen.io/emekdev/pen/NWNvLpj

```
<div id="header-content">
            <h1 id="title">Mustafa Kemal Atatürk</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Early life</li>
                    <li>Military career</li>
                    <li>Presidency</li>
                    <li>Personal life</li>
                    <li>Illness and death</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>  
        </div>
```

It is my animation div container.

```
#header-content {
    animation-name: header-content-fade-in;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

ul:nth-child(1) {animation-delay: .5s;}
ul:nth-child(2) {animation-delay: 1s;}
ul:nth-child(3) {animation-delay: 1.5s;}
ul:nth-child(4) {animation-delay: 2s;}
ul:nth-child(5) {animation-delay: 2.5s;}
```

In here, I'm trying to give different animation delays to all of my child elements. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You are applying the animation to the div ....not the elements inside. If you want them to appear in order you have to apply the animation to those elements.

Answer (score 1):

```css
li {
  animation: header-content-fade-in 4s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
li:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0.5s; }
li:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 1s; }
li:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 1.5s; }
li:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 2s; }
li:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 2.5s; }

@keyframes header-content-fade-in {
  to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div id="header-content">
  <h1 id="title">Mustafa Kemal Atatürk</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Early life</li>
      <li>Military career</li>
      <li>Presidency</li>
      <li>Personal life</li>
      <li>Illness and death</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```